# Raw State Data on Health and Social Outcomes

Tags: data, csv, excel, united-states

I am looking for raw health and social outcome data (poverty, obesity, education levels, etc.) by state. I would like to download it as a csv or excel file.  It needs to have the state fips listed in one of the columns.

There is a lot of county data out there, but can anyone point me in the right directions for state data?

Comment: This looks like a question more suited to the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just aggregate using the [BRFSS](http://www.cdc.gov/brfss/annual_data/annual_data.htm) for chronic disease indicators? It has State FIPS for almost all respondents, as well as County FIPS for the majority of respondents (mostly in urban areas, and rural areas are mostly censored to the state).

You could also try using [sortable stats](http://wwwn.cdc.gov/sortablestats/).

For poverty and education levels, you could aggregate the Area Health Resource File ([AHRF](http://arf.hrsa.gov/download.htm)) data which has records based on county.

Basically, what I am trying to say is, AGGREGATE the statistics.

Comment: That sounds like the ticket! Can you point me in the right direction as to how to aggregate an excel speadsheet or shapefile into state statistics? Thank you!

Comment: In excel, you could use the SUMIF() function to aggregate numerators and denominators by each State FIPS. In shapefiles, you could use the dissolve tool (although I am unsure if this is the same in QGIS or other GIS packages).